# Oracle performance database size increases

Tags: oracle

I have a high level question. Say I have a SQL query that takes 30ms to complete, it runs against an indexed column on a table with 1million records. Now if the table size is increased to 5million records should I expect the query to take 5 times as long (as 5 times the indexes have to be searched), so 150ms. I apologise if this is too simplistic, I have a program that is running 10 SQL (indexed) against a table that is going to be increased by this factor, the queries currently take 300ms and I am concerned this would increase to 1.5s. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Short answer: no.  The whole point of indexes is that they offer (much) faster than O(N) lookup performance.

Comment: The amount of I/O it takes to look up a single row by a uniuqe index is pretty much constant, regardless of the size of the table (there are of course some thresholds where "constant" is no longer true, but then the amount increases by just one or two additional I/O operations). The time it takes to read **all** rows of a table is of course directly dependent on the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of an index lookup as doing a search through a binary tree followed by a fetch of the page with the appropriate data.  Typically, the index would fit in memory and the search through the index would be quite fast.  Multiplying the data size of 10 would increase the depth of the tree by 3 or 4.  With in-memory comparison operations this would not be noticeable for most queries.  (There are other types of indexes besides binary b-trees, but this is a convenient model for thinking about performance.)

The data fetch then could incur the overhead of reading a page from disk.  That should still be quite fast.

So, the easy answer to your question is:  no.  However, this assumes that the query is something like:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.indexcol = CONSTANTVALUE
```

And, it assumes that the query only returns one row.  Things that might affect the performance as the table size increases include:

- The size of the returned data set increases with the size of the table.  Returning more values necessarily takes longer.  For some queries, the performance is more dependent on the mechanism for returning values than calculating/fetching the data.
- The query contains `join` or `group by`.
- The statistics of the table are up-to-date, so the optimizer doesn't accidentally choose a full table scan rather than an index lookup.
- You are in a memory-constrained environment where the index doesn't fit in memory.  Or, the entire table is in memory when smaller but incurs the overhead of a cache-miss as it gets larger.